# How to get results from search result activity?

Tags: java, android, searchview

I have an Activity (MainActivity) with a search button in the action bar. It searches by some input string and shows the results in a ListView in another Activity (SearchResultsActivity). The user might click in any result to select it.

I want to return the value selected by the user to the main activity, but it's not working. I looked in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html) but I didn't find anything related.
I tried to use setResult(Intent) in the results activity but the onActivityResult() from the main activity never gets called.

What am I doing wrong? How can I do it?

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="foo.bar" >

    <!-- ... -->

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <!-- Main Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main">

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                android:value=".SearchResultsActivity" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Search results activity -->
        <activity android:name=".SearchResultsActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Menu.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!-- Search -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />

    <!-- ... -->
</menu>
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    // ...

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        final MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_menu, menu);

        // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // never gets called!
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    // ...
}
```

SearchResultsActivity:

```
public class SearchResultsActivity extends Activity {
    private ListView listResults;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search_results);

        // get the action bar
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        // Enabling Back navigation on Action Bar icon
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        listResults = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listResults);

        handleIntent(getIntent());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        setIntent(intent);
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    /**
     * Handling intent data
     */
    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);

            final Serializable[] results = find(query);

            listResults.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<BusLine>(this, R.layout.list_view, busLines));
            listResults.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Serializable selectedResult = (Serializable) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, new Intent().putExtra("result", selectedResult));
                    finish();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can understand why you might think that you would use setResult and onActivityResult to handle clicks in your search results activity, but that is not how it works. Only when you launch an activity with startActivityForResult do these functions apply -- not when displaying search results.

The solution is to call startActivity on your MainActivity in the normal fashion, that is, not using activity results. Something like this:

```
listResults.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Serializable selectedResult = (Serializable) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("result", selectedResult);
        intent.setClass(SearchResultsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
});
```

Now you will also need to capture this search result in your MainActivity, although you need to make sure you handle the normal case as well as the search results case:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent.hasExtra("result")) {
        // Launched from search results
        Serializable selectedResult = (Serializable) intent.getSerializableExtra("result");
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I could not find onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle) on FragmentActivity so I put that part in the onCreate(Bundle) and that worked. Is it right?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. Most of my code is in my fragments, and so I'm used to onCreateView. Editing my answer ...

Comment: How about if you have several user Activities for the searchableActivity (e.g. SearchResultsActivity)? Sounds kind of funny to me that searchableActivity should explicitly know the caller.